# Angular6 *ngFor table with objects in object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular 6 tables but i'm facing a trouble with a `*ngFor` item.

This is my html view

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">Cuenta</th>
    <th class="text-center">ENE 2018</th>
    <th class="text-center">Proy. Lineal</th>
    <th class="text-center">Proy. Sugerida</th>
    <th class="text-center">Proy. Comercial</th>
    <th class="text-center">Presupuesto a convenir</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of centroData; let id = index">
    <td>
      <span>{{data.id}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ENE2018}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ProyLinealCalculado}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ProySugeridaCalculado}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ProyComercialCalculado}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.Presupuesto}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is my component.ts array

```
centroData: Array<any> = [
    {
      id: 123333123,
      ENE2018: 1340300,
      ProyLinealCalculado: 1393939,
      ProySugeridaCalculado: 1239393,
      ProyComercialCalculado: 3039430,
      Presupuesto: null,
      subcuentas: [
        {
          id: 1,
          folio: "123333123-01",
          ENE2018: 39394,
          ProyLinealCalculado: 1393939,
          ProySugeridaCalculado: 1239393,
          ProyComercialCalculado: 3039430,
          Presupuesto: null
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          folio: "123333123-02",
          ENE2018: 39394,
          ProyLinealCalculado: 1393939,
          ProySugeridaCalculado: 1239393,
          ProyComercialCalculado: 3039430,
          Presupuesto: null
        }
      ]
    }
 ];`
```

Basically, what I want to do is add a new `<tr>` that is `subcuentas`, of course this is only 1 element in the array, but when it comes with 2 or more.

**What's in my mind**

I know I can't access `data.subcuentas` by adding a second `*ngFor` inside the first `*ngFor` cause it's a table which `<tr>` breaks the row.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used ng-container tag to achieve this. See the below code. Hope this helps.

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">Cuenta</th>
    <th class="text-center">ENE 2018</th>
    <th class="text-center">Proy. Lineal</th>
    <th class="text-center">Proy. Sugerida</th>
    <th class="text-center">Proy. Comercial</th>
    <th class="text-center">Presupuesto a convenir</th>
  </tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of centroData; let id = index">
    <tr>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.id}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ENE2018}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ProyLinealCalculado}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ProySugeridaCalculado}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ProyComercialCalculado}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.Presupuesto}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let data of data.subcuentas; let id = index">
    <td>
      <span>{{data.id}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ENE2018}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ProyLinealCalculado}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ProySugeridaCalculado}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.ProyComercialCalculado}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>{{data.Presupuesto}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>

  </ng-container>

  </table>
```

**Output:**

[image]

About ng-container element.

1. [Explain ng-container Element](http://www.javapedia.net/module/Angular#qanda2861)
2. https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#group-sibling-elements-with-ng-container

Comment: Thanks, that's what i needed. I'm new to Angular so i miss this details.